# Cannot redirect stdout to file specified by full path

Tags: linux, bash, sed, io-redirection

Let

```
CONFIG_FILE=${WWW_DIR}/${WORDPRESS_TEST_DIR}/wp-config.php
```

This **doesn't** work:

```
sed "${SED_ARG}" ${CONFIG_FILE} >| ${CONFIG_FILE}
```

(all I get is an empty file). It does not work either when I replace the variables with the actual path strings, nor when I escape the paths with ".

This **does** work:

```
sed "${SED_ARG}" ${CONFIG_FILE} >| wp-config.php
mv wp-config.php ${CONFIG_FILE}
```

so I would assume the `sed` call works just fine.

Strangely, this **does** work too:

```
echo TEST >| ${CONFIG_FILE}
```

so the `sed` part might be the problem after all. I am clueless. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The redirection opens the file for writing (not appending), which makes it a new empty file, before the `sed` command is executed.

You can use the `-i` flag of sed, to do an in place substitution:

```
sed -I "${SED_ARG}" "${CONFIG_FILE}"
```

I also put quotes around `${CONFIG_FILE}` to avoid unexpected behavior if it contains any special characters.